# Is it safe to reuse ContentValues for several insert() to table operations?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Is it safe to reuse the same `ContentValues` instance while writing a list of objects to database?

```
ContentValues row = new ContentValues();
for (Businessman businessman : aLotOfBusinessmen) {
    row.put(BusinessmanEntry.COLUMN_ADDRESS, businessman.getAddress());
    row.put(BusinessmanEntry.COLUMN_CASH, businessman.getCash());
    db.insert(BusinessmanEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, row);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Not only is it safe, it's also better, since you will avoid the memory allocations (and subsequent GC) associated with creating a distinct instance of `ContentValues` for each execution of the loop body.